# It is an easy packing list in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, packing

As a private exercise i tried to write a small python program. 
I am travelling a lot and always look for the same stuff. therefore I was thinking it makes sense to have a packing list.

My input is occuption, mobility, wheater, and duration.
My output is a list with items.

My file is much larger, but here are the essential parts of the program

```
    packinglist = []

    clothes = ["T-Shirt(s)", "Extra Shoes", "Ironed Shirts"]

    occupation = []
    while occupation != "Business" or occupation !="Private" or occupation         
    !="Outdoor":

        occupation =str(input('Whats the purpose: Business, Private, or Outdoor?\n'))
    if occupation == "Business" or occupation =="Private" or occupation =="Outdoor":
        print("Okay. Go on!\n")
        break

    while True:
    try:
        days = int(input('How many days are you travelling?\n'))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Wrong Entry, please type in a posive number!")
```

I included plenty of conditions like:

```
    if days >2 and occupation=="Business":
        packinglist.append(hardware[2])     #Shaver
        packinglist.append(personals[9])    #Watch
        packinglist.append(documents[5])    #Card Wallet


    packinglist1 = list( dict.fromkeys(packinglist))

    print("---clothes---:\n")
    for clothes_id in packinglist1:
        if clothes_id in clothes:
            print(clothes_id)
        else:
            pass


    print("\n")
    print("---Summary.---\n")
    print("Your Trip is for:", occupation)
    print("Wheater condition:", wheater)
    print("Sports activites:", sport)
    print("Days of duration:", days)
```

Here I add the option to include individually stuff for the specific journey

```
    names = []
    new_object = ''
    while new_object != 'quit':
        new_object = input("You want to add something to the list?, or enter 'quit': ")
        packinglist1.append(new_object)
```

There are a bunch of more beautiful ways of coding, but I am not yet able to do. Therefore, If you like you can give me a recommendation how to improve the program.

I think it would be good to have model that takes the "days" of the journey into account. Furthermore, a good visualization with e.g. Tkinter would look really nice. Lets see what comes up

Comment: This is not a question that belongs on Stack Overflow. But take a look at [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), there they will happily review your code.

Comment: This question is not a good fit for CodeReview - it is not complete. Make sure to read their rules before posting to avoid grief.

Comment: Beside that - it has IndexErrors. Hence not runnign. Hence no for for CodeReview at all.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I will check CodeReview. Here, it is by far not the full code.